# Is it faster to use LINQ to get a row from a List or a foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

Is LINQ the faster method to use to select a row from a List?

EG

```
var matchingStaticPricingResult =
                    (staticPricingResult.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(a => new { a.alias, a.price, specialPricing = true })
                    .Where(a => a.alias.ToLower() == product.Alias.ToLower())
                    .Take(1)).ToList();
```

vs

```
foreach(var item in staticPricingResult){
    if(item.alias.equals(product.Alias){
        //dostuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you wrap it and find out??

Comment: Well both linq and a foreach loop use an obejcts IEnumerable implementation to work.  So they will be pretty equivalent in that regard.  However a for next loop "for (int i = 0... etc" is faster than both because you are looping on a counter and getting the objects by their index (which on a List<T> is really fast)

Comment: @Ryios: The enumerator isn't much slower than that.

Comment: The code in your two examples is quite different.  Use `.First()`.

Comment: @Slaks, true, but you still get about a 5% increase using for over foreach on most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

`LINQ` internally iterates just as `foreach` does. LINQ is lazy for most operations, it won't actually do anything until someone starts enumerating the results.

Refer the following links for more info.

[FOR vs FOREACH vs LINQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178218/for-vs-foreach-vs-linq)

[LINQ vs FOREACH vs FOR Loop Performance](http://www.schnieds.com/2009/03/linq-vs-foreach-vs-for-loop-performance.html)

[LINQ vs FOREACH Round 1](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/04/23/c-linq-vs-foreach---round-1.aspx)

Comment: Not just that. LINQ creates a class and there is a heap allocation that takes place behind the scenes to get this work. That's not the case with foreach.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there is any special benefit of that? I read LINQ is a bit slower than for loop.

Comment: it's just one of the ways to implement LINQ I believe. No special benifits.

Comment: @Jagannath: Each LINQ method must return an object; that object must live on the heap.